# Large copy of data from external HardDrive intermittently stops

Tags: hard-drive, usb

I'm copying about 200 GB of music from my backup 1TB hard drive onto my PC, and after about every 20-30 seconds, I get a warning about "Item Not Found", almost as if my USB is being repeatedly uninserted/reinserted.

Is there a problem with my USB Hard-Drive?

Comment: Is the USB HD in an enclosure of some kind? Some enclosures may have a time out feature

Comment: What operating system are you using?  Sounds like Windows.  Are you manually doing `Ctrl+C` + `Ctrl+V` or copying it via a script, command, or other program?

Comment: No enclosure. Windows 8.1. Ctrl-C -> Ctrl-V.